# Oracle - Why HAVING clause can be before GROUP BY

Tags: oracle, group-by, having

Why/How [HAVING clause](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefselectexpression.html#rrefselectexpression) can be before GROUP BY

```
select count(1) from tableA
having id >1
group by id
order by count(1)
```

I know `HAVING` clause can be without `GROUP BY` clause,

But when defining `GROUP BY` why `HAVING` isn't forced so to be after, as `ORDER BY` clause?

> Derby processes a SelectExpression in the following order:

> - FROM clause
> - WHERE clause
> - GROUP BY (or implicit GROUP BY)
> - HAVING clause
> - ORDER BY clause

In all docs it appears after `GROUP BY`:

> ```
> GROUP BY WORKDEPT 
> HAVING MAX(SALARY) < (SELECT AVG(SALARY)
>                          FROM EMPLOYEE
>                          WHERE NOT WORKDEPT = EMP_COR.WORKDEPT)
> ```

**EDIT** [Oreilly](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-oracle-sql/0596001290/ch04s03.html) article states order is not important (but not why)

> The order of the GROUP BY clause and the HAVING clause in a SELECT statement is not important. We can specify the GROUP BY clause before the HAVING clause, or vice versa

I suspect because *HAVING* can be without *GROUP BY* clause then order isn't enforced.

Comment: This must be the overloaded `HAVING` clause, similar to MySQL.  Your `HAVING` clause is actually being evaluated as a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It seems that the `HAVING` clause is executed after `GROUP BY`

Comment: It doesn't matter for a restriction on `id`, which is also the column by which you are grouping.  Throwing away the entire group after `GROUP BY`, or throwing way all records in the group before `GROUP BY` is the same thing.

Comment: Logically I agree `having` belongs after `group by`. However, you can write it back to front if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because  the having clause work on the result  (filter the result of the select  )

a query select  could be base only on the select or  if is an aggreagtion query
 the result  is produced  after the GROUP BY 
 this way  sematically the HAVING is placed  ad the end of the query CLAUSE  ..  just before the presentation clause  (ORDER BY)

Comment: This is not a complete answer, provides no doc references, etc.

Comment: The link is to something called "Java DB". It seems to have the same syntax as normal Oracle SQL though, whatever it is.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - "Java DB" is Oracle's distribution of [Apache Derby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Derby), a relational database written in (surprise, surprise) Java. IIRC Derby (originally JBMS; also known as Cloudscape) had its statement syntax (but not datatypes) modeled after Oracle.